# How to add a github function to an existing android studio program

Tags: java, android, github

In the past I could load a github program to work in my android studio program but with the last update either I went full stupid or something is wrong.  I am trying to get this https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer in my program and I am adding my compile in my app and downloading and unzipping the program.  When I add the view to my app it breaks.  I hope you guys can help because I feel a bit crazy at the moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to load the project, you may import as a eclipse project to migrate to AS + gradle.

If you are trying to use as library, AndroidStudio made it difficult to add libraries that are not as a artefact loaded by gradle.
So usually you find the gradle dependency into the project page and add it into your gradle, in your case it is exactly:

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0'
```

Comment: I have added the compile and my gradle rebuilds but when I add the view to my layout my layout breaks.

Comment: I am trying to use the pdfview in my app and I am using android studios but should I start using eclipse if I want to use github?

Comment: No, gradle is the way to add libraries without downloading sourcecode, your must create your own project and add the gradle dependency as I stated in your build.gradle

Comment: yes I understand that.  I added the `compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0'` to my build.gradle (module: app).  I added the compile to my dependencies inside of the build.gradle yet it still doesnt work.

Comment: What happens? you means layoutbreaks but it is compile time or runtime?

Comment: So when you add the compile into the build.gradle you have to rebuild the gradle which it does but when i go to add `<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>` to my layout and then i go from text to design but i get a nothing to show in my component tree.

Comment: Well, I would not rely on Design View of layouts, cant you test in runtime?

Comment: I got a different one to work.  I have no idea what is wrong with like half of github android projects.